# Android google play services SDK

Tags: java, android

Am having a strange problem , I installed the Google Play Services SDK following the instruction site , but I can't find the lib folder
[image]

any ideas what is causing this ?

Comment: Check the location of the SDK that is set in eclipse preferences. Is it the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is the location of google-play-services_lib

```
\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

From your directory, you are one step away from it.If it's not there then maybe you need to restart your computer or change your sdk path and try to re-download it.